# FlashLED intensity controls

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdk-2.3, flashlight, android-hardware

I am looking for help in Android camera LED Flash for changing intensity of it like [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devuni.flashlight).

I have checked following link but i am not getting exact result from it.

1. [Can I change the LED intensity of an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970188/can-i-change-the-led-intensity-of-an-android-device)
2. [How to turn on camera flash light programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068803/how-turn-on-camera-flash-light-programmatically-in-android)
3. http://code.google.com/p/droidled/source/checkout
4. http://code.google.com/p/simpleled/source/checkout
5. https://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/checkout

And I am not able to execute [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Tools/quick-settings/com/bwx/bequick/flashlight/Catalogflashlight.htm) (it seems promising to me).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970188/can-i-change-the-led-intensity-of-an-android-device

Comment: I have already mention it in my first link of question.

Comment: +1 This shows plenty of research efforts.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970188/can-i-change-the-led-intensity-of-an-android-device/6959591#6959591)

HTC has an alternative API that supports this, however it's only on HTC Sense devices, and as of Gingerbread they've changed the permissions so it's only for their Flashlight app, not third party ones (unless you use root).

But on 2.2 HTC devices you can use it by writing a string to `/sys/devices/platform/flashlight.0/leds/flashlight/brightness`. This controls if the LED is on and how bright it is. For maximum brightness write `"128\n"`, half brightness write `"64\n"`. Easy to test from adb shell:

```
echo "128" > /sys/devices/platform/flashlight.0/leds/flashlight/brightness
```

And finally turn it off by writing `"0\n"` there.