# Controlling the brightness of the flashlight in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to develop an android application using a penlight. When I use the flashlight, brightness is too strong. I want to reduce the brightness of the flash light. I have used camera and Flash Mode as TORCH. Can someone please help to to reduce the brightness of the flashlight.
Thank you..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the LED intensity of an Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970188/can-i-change-the-led-intensity-of-an-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no reliable solution for this as there is no official Android API for this kind of functionality.
There is a hacky "solution" that works on some rooted devices. But as I said, nothing reliable. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701937/is-the-flashlight-intensity-brightness-controllable-on-android).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another hack (life hack)If you need a less intense light on your android just go to your Google search or any page that's predominantly white (or set to dark mode for black screen if you need it even dimmer than what the white screen produces ) and turn the brightness up or down on your screen, with the pull down menu, while on this page you can adjust it and use it for a slightly dimmer light (I've used my phone to draw in bed at night time ) probably why you don't see many apps focused on dimming the flashlight.. I think most people would rather use this life hack than take up more space with another Application. Then again who knows

Comment: Hello Greycloud420, welcome to stackoverflow.
Your reply does not answer the question, this could have been a comment.
Please check how to have better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32620719)