# How to increase and decrease the flashlight brightness in android

Tags: android, flashlight

I have not found a single link for increasing and decreasing the flashlight intensity of Mobile phone. If any one know, Please provide a solution to me or refer a link.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately there is no reliable solution for this as there is no official Android API for this kind of functionality. There is a hacky "solution" that works on some rooted devices. But as I said, nothing reliable. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701937/is-the-flashlight-intensity-brightness-controllable-on-android).

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167430/controlling-the-brightness-of-the-flashlight-in-android)