# Android Flashlight Help neded

Tags: android, flashlight

Is there a way to code the power of the android phone flashlight **20%,30%,40%** ?
*I don't need the code just an answer to the question, if there is one i will want to find it myself*

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the LED intensity of an Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970188/can-i-change-the-led-intensity-of-an-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. When I looked into this a while ago I looked at the CyanogenMod's Flashlight app. It uses underlying system calls that you don't have in the standard Android API.

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970188/can-i-change-the-led-intensity-of-an-android-device)..One of the answers in that link says..

```
Short answer is: NO.
Longer answer - maybe on some devices using undocumenterd calls / parameters. Supported 
flash modes, and their meanings (and behaviours) differ from device to device.

Your best option is to query supported flash modes, and hope they work as intented.
```