# How can we increase or decrease intensity of flash light android?

Tags: java, android

I want to increase and decrease flash light intensity of android in my torch app and provide it on seekbar so that user can control the intensity.

Comment: Afaik this is not possible. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970188/can-i-change-the-led-intensity-of-an-android-device

Comment: got my answer Thanks for quick response....