# Is there a way to make lower / higher flash light in Android programmatically

Tags: android

I know there is a way to turn on / off the flash light. But is there a way to make the light lower / higher from the app programmatically?

Comment: Please show your current code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change the LED intensity of an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970188/can-i-change-the-led-intensity-of-an-android-device)