# Change torch brightness while camera preview is working in android

Tags: android, camera, torch, cameraapi2

In Android 13 (API 33) a new control is appeared to adjust torch brightness:

`public void turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel ( cameraId, int torchStrength)`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager#turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(java.lang.String,%20int)

But invoking this function during a working camera preview raises an Exception:
*android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_IN_USE (4): turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel:2596: Torch for camera “0” is not available due to an existing camera user*

The only way to use simple torch during preview is to adjust capture request builder with option like so:
`builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, if (isOn) CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH else CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)`
But it doesn't allow to modify flashlight brightness.

I have such kind of code just to switch ON/OFF torch during camera preview. And it's working fine.

```
    override fun switchTorch(isOn: Boolean) {
        if (cameraOpened.get()) {

            val session = captureSession
            val builderAndHandler = captureRequestBuilderWithHandler

            if (session != null && builderAndHandler != null) {
                val (builder, handler) = builderAndHandler
                session.stopRepeating()
                isTorchInProgress = isOn
                builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, if (isOn) CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH else CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
                session.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(), null, handler)
            }
        } else {
            postponedSwitchTorch = isOn
        }
    }
```

I tried to implement a function for Android 13 only to modify brightness level like so:

```
override fun setTorchStrengthLevel(level: Int) {
    Log.d("qaz", "Api2. setTorchStrengthLevel: $level")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        if (cameraOpened.get()) {

            val session = captureSession
            val builderAndHandler = captureRequestBuilderWithHandler

            if (session != null && builderAndHandler != null) {
                val (builder, handler) = builderAndHandler
                session.stopRepeating()
                cameraManager.turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(cameraDevice.id, level)
                builder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
                session.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(), null, handler)
            } else {
                Log.w("qaz", "skip setTorch, because session or buildANdHandler are null")
            }
        } else {
            Log.w("qaz", "skip setTorch, because camera is not opened")
        }
    } else {
        throw IllegalAccessException("This function should be called only on Android T or higher")
    }
}
```

And it throws an exception in call **turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(cameraDevice.id, level)**
*CameraAccessException: CAMERA_IN_USE (4): turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel:2596: Torch for camera "0" is not available due to an existing camera user

How I can change torch brightness while camera preview is working on Android 13 (T)?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently and couldn't find a good solution until now. This is the code I have that works on AN 13, maybe it can be helpful to you or someone else:

```
    private fun startTorch(cameraId: String) {
    cameraManager.torchCamera?.let {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU &&
            cameraOptions.containsKey(cameraId)
        ) {
            val characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(it)
            val supportsMaxLevel = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_STRENGTH_MAXIMUM_LEVEL)
            if (supportsMaxLevel != null && supportsMaxLevel > 1) {
                cameraManager.turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel(
                    it,
                    cameraOptions[it]!!.flashPower
                )
            } else {
                cameraManager.setTorchMode(it, true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```